# How to avoid race condition in this python scripts?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, race-condition

I made a function which gives inconsistent results if ran on single-core and multi-core, probably due to a race condition. However, I am relatively new to this topic, so I didn't know how to handle such problem. This is the function I am trying to edit in order to avoid race condition. Any help would be appreciated

```
def trimer_retrieve(tupleargs):
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import operator
    from itertools import product
    db=tupleargs[0]
    pos=tupleargs[1]
    mut=tupleargs[2]
    db=pd.read_csv(db,delimiter="\t")
    dbd={ db.loc[idx]['SEQUENCE_IMGT'][0:-1].replace(".","X").replace("-","D"):int(db.loc[idx]['COUNT'])
    for idx in db.index if db.loc[idx]['SEQUENCE_ID'] !='GERM' }
    germ=[db.loc[idx]['SEQUENCE_IMGT'].replace(".","X").replace("-","D")
    for idx in db.index if db.loc[idx]['SEQUENCE_ID'] =='GERM' ][0]
    dbg={i:{'ref':germ[i], 'A':0,'C':0,'T':0,'G':0,'X':0,'D':0,'N':0} for i in range(len(germ)) }
    if int(pos) <= 2:
        pv='NNN'
        fol=[]
        for seq in dbd.keys():
            if seq[ int(pos) ] == str(mut):
                fol.append((seq[int(pos)+1:int(pos)+4],dbd[seq]))
        fol_dct={ ''.join(p):0 for p in product(['A','C','T','G'],repeat=3) }
        for p in fol:
            fol_dct[p[0]]+=p[1]
        fd=max(fol_dct,key=fol_dct.get)
    elif int(pos) >= len(dbg) -3:
        fd='NNN'
        prev=[]
        for seq in dbd.keys():
            if seq[ df.loc[idx]['pos'] ] == df.loc[idx]['alt']:
                prev.append((seq[df.loc[idx]['pos']-3:df.loc[idx]['pos']],dbd[seq]))
        prev_dct={ ''.join(p):0 for p in product(['A','C','T','G'],repeat=3) }
        for p in prev:
            prev_dct[p[0]]+=p[1]
        pv=max(prev_dct,key=prev_dct.get)
    elif int(pos) > 2 and int(pos) < len(dbg) -3 :
        prev=[]
        fol=[]
        for seq in dbd.keys():
            if seq[ int(pos) ] == str(mut):
                gaps=[(r.start(),r.end()) for r in re.finditer(r'X{1,}',seq)]
                prev_g=["T" if int(pos)-3 not in range(g[0],g[1]+1) else "F" for g in gaps ]
                fol_g=["T" if int(pos)+3 not in range(g[0],g[1]+1) else "F" for g in gaps ]
                if 'F' not in fol_g :
                    if 'F' not in prev_g:
                        prev.append((seq[int(pos)-3:int(pos)],dbd[seq]))
                        fol.append((seq[int(pos)+1:int(pos)+4],dbd[seq]))
                    else:
                        idx_gap=[idx for idx,val in enumerate(prev_g) if val == 'F' ][0]
                        gi=gaps[idx_gap]
                        trimer=seq[ int(pos)-3:int(pos) ]
                        strt=re.search(r'[A,C,G,T]{1,}',trimer)
                        if strt != None :
                            n_g=trimer[strt.start():]
                            n_ng=seq[gi[0]-3+len(n_g):gi[0]]
                            prev.append((n_ng + n_g, dbd[seq]))
                        else:
                            n_g=seq[gi[0]-3:gi[0]]
                            prev.append((n_g,dbd[seq]))
                if 'F' in fol_g :
                    if 'F' not in prev_g:
                        prev.append((seq[int(pos)-3:int(pos)],dbd[seq]))
                        idx_gap=[idx for idx,val in enumerate(fol_g) if val == 'F' ][0]
                        gi=gaps[idx_gap]
                        trimer=seq[ int(pos)+1:int(pos)+4 ]
                        strt=re.search(r'[A,C,G,T]{1,}',trimer)
                        if strt != None :
                            n_g=trimer[:strt.start()+1]
                            n_ng=seq[gi[1]:gi[1]+3-len(n_g)]
                            prev.append((n_g+n_ng,dbd[seq]))
                        else:
                            n_g=seq[gi[1]:gi[1]+3]
                            prev.append((n_g,dbd[seq]))
        prev_dct={ ''.join(p):0 for p in product(['A','C','T','G'],repeat=3) }
        for p in prev:
            prev_dct[p[0]]+=p[1]
        pv=max(prev_dct,key=prev_dct.get)
        fol_dct={ ''.join(p):0 for p in product(['A','C','T','G'],repeat=3) }
        for p in fol:
            fol_dct[p[0]]+=p[1]
        fd=max(fol_dct,key=fol_dct.get)
    return(pv,fd)
```

I ran this function with multiprocessing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        trimers=pool.map(trimer_retrieve,tupleargs )
```

The df from which I took parameters for tupleargs has this structure:
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fOA.png)

tupleargs is generated in this way:

```
tupleargs=[(args.input,df.loc[idx]['pos'],df.loc[idx]['alt']) for idx in df.index ]
```

wheread the imported db has this structure;
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsK08.png)

Comment: There's no multiprocessing in your code.

Comment: I edited the comment. I am using multiprocessing with pool.map

Comment: `pv` and `fd` are local variables, each thread has its own variables.

Comment: You can only have race conditions if you update data that's shared between the threads.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Since it is not possible to have race condition in this way, how is possible that results differ between single and multi-core?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and show how the results differ.

Comment: I debugged the function and I observed that INSIDE the function pv and fd overwrited in some circumstances. Now I fixed it, it wasn't race condition. Thanks for your help!